# How to import Powershell CSV month names

Tags: powershell, csv, sorting, parsing, foreach

I have a CSV (5k lines) that is formatted from a software with this header:

```
groupname,id,name,email,active,created,Last seen in software A,Last seen in software B,Last seen in software C,Software A,Software B,Software C
```

And the lines below look like this:
`test-group,userID123,John Doe,jdoe@company.com,Yes,18 May 2017,22 Jun 2020,22 Jun 2020,22 Jun 2020,No,Yes,Yes`

---

I was wondering, given that the CSV has the date formated into "Day, Month Name, Year" how I can filter the data.
For example: Id like to filter people who I havent seen in the last 90 days and also the result only searchs if "Software A" is on condition yes.

Also i'd like to add more parameters, for example looking if the user has: -and (email -like "*company.com") or etc.

I have previous experience on searching on AD, but not importing from a CSV.

```
$daysnumber= Read-Host 'Days since login'
(get-date).adddays(-$daysnumber)
$data = import-csv "userlist.csv"
$data | foreach-object {
New-Object PSObject -prop @{
"Last Seen in Software A" = [DateTime]::Parse("$_.Last Seen in Software A")
}
}
```

---UPDATE---
I went on to a different road. I've replaced the format for the date so I no longer have to deal with the Month name.
But I'm having issues to verify the data and even display it on the console or outputting to a CSV file..

```bsh
#Reads the file and then change all the months name to numeric value for ease of acces and sorting.
$original_file = 'C:\SCRIPTS\data\export-users.csv'
$destination_file =  'C:\SCRIPTS\data\export-users-replaced.csv'
(Get-Content $original_file) | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -replace 'Jan', '01' `
       -replace 'Feb', '02' `
       -replace 'Mar', '03' `
       -replace 'Apr', '04' `
       -replace 'May', '05' `
       -replace 'Jun', '06' `
       -replace 'Jul', '07' `
       -replace 'Aug', '08' `
       -replace 'Sep', '09' `
       -replace 'Oct', '10' `
       -replace 'Nov', '11' `
       -replace 'Dec', '12' `
       -replace 'Never logged in', '01 01 1990' `
    } | Set-Content $destination_file

    

#properties    = 'groupname','id','name','email','active','created','Last seen in Jira Service Desk','Last seen in Jira Software','Last seen in Confluence','Jira Service Desk','Jira Software','Confluence'
Import-Csv $destination_file | ForEach-Object {
    $groupname += $_.groupname
    $id += $_.id
    $name += $_.name
    $email += $_.email
    $active += $_.active
    #JSD (Jira service desk)
    $lastjsd += $_."Last Seen in Jira Service Desk"
    #JSW (Jira Software)
    $lastjsw += $_."Last seen in Jira Software"
    #JCF (Jira Confluence)
    $lastjcf += $_."Last Seen in Confluence"
    $licjsd += $_."Jira Service Desk"
    $licjsw += $_."Jira Software"
    $licjcf += $_.Confluence
} 

# Write-Host $active

$daysnumber= Read-Host 'Cantidad de dias'
$emaildomain=Read-Host 'Dominio de mails. Escriba "@dominio.com"'
$days   =  (get-date).adddays(-$daysnumber).ToString('dd MM yyyy')
Write-Host "Si desea buscar licencias de Service Desk ingrese Service,
Si desea buscar licencias de Jira Software ingrese Software,
Si desea buscar licencias de Confluence ingrese Confluence"

$license= Read-Host " ( service / software / confluence ) "
    switch ($license) {
        service {Where-Object $lastjcf -LE $days | Format-List | Out-String | Export-Csv -Path "C:\SCRIPTS\jiratest.csv"   -Encoding UTF8 -Append -NoTypeInformation
         }
        software { Write-Host "nope"}
        confluence { Write-Host "no"}
    }

# Select-Object email -eq *$emaildomain* -and 'Last seen in Confluence' -le $days


# -and $licjsd -eq "Yes" -and $active -Is "Yes"
```

Hope that someone can guide me on how to make this trough!

Thanks.

Comment: `(get-date).adddays(-$daysnumber)` --> `$daysSince = (Get-Date).AddDays(-[int]$daysnumber).Date` and `[DateTime]::Parse("$_.Last Seen in Software A")` --> `[datetime]::ParseExact($_.'Last Seen in Software A', 'dd MMM yyyy', $null)`

Comment: @Theo ! Thanks for the info! I didn't have luck with the code, because I had a lot of parsing errors. I went on to a different route. Will attach my code below.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a need to replace all month short names into numeric values, but below I have added a comment in front of the `$format` variable, so you ca set that as you need.

Also, there is (as far as I can tell) no need to create array-like variables for all the fields in the CSV, because after Import-Csv they are all available anyway.

Try this shortened code:

```
# 'groupname','id','name','email','active','created','Last seen in Jira Service Desk','Last seen in Jira Software','Last seen in Confluence','Jira Service Desk','Jira Software','Confluence'
$data = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\SCRIPTS\data\export-users.csv'

$daysnumber  = Read-Host 'Cantidad de dias'                # remember that Read-Host returns a string
$emaildomain = Read-Host 'Dominio de mails. Escriba "@dominio.com"'
$days        = (Get-Date).AddDays(-[int]$daysnumber).Date  # get a DateTime object and disregard the time part (set to midnight)

Write-Host "Si desea buscar licencias de Service Desk ingrese Service,
Si desea buscar licencias de Jira Software ingrese Software,
Si desea buscar licencias de Confluence ingrese Confluence"

$license = Read-Host " ( service / software / confluence ) "

# the date format used to parse out the date from the CSV file
$format  = 'dd MM yyyy'   # for dates like '22 Jun 2020' use 'dd MMM yyyy'

switch ($license) {
    'service' {
        $fileOut  = 'C:\SCRIPTS\jiraServiceDeskTest.csv'
        $property = 'Last Seen in Jira Service Desk'
        $data | Where-Object { [datetime]::ParseExact($_.$property, $format, $null) -le $days } | 
                Export-Csv -Path $fileOut -Encoding UTF8 -Append -NoTypeInformation
    }
    'software' { 
        $fileOut  = 'C:\SCRIPTS\jiraSoftwareTest.csv'
        $property = 'Last seen in Jira Software'
        $data | Where-Object { [datetime]::ParseExact($_.$property, $format, $null) -le $days } | 
                Export-Csv -Path $fileOut -Encoding UTF8 -Append -NoTypeInformation
    }
    'confluence' { 
        $fileOut  = 'C:\SCRIPTS\jiraConfluenceTest.csv'
        $property = 'Last Seen in Confluence'
        $data | Where-Object { [datetime]::ParseExact($_.$property, $format, $null) -le $days } | 
                Export-Csv -Path $fileOut -Encoding UTF8 -Append -NoTypeInformation
    }
    default { Write-Host "Wrong input" } 
}
```

<sup>It is advisable to (later) add tests to see if the user input from the various `Read-Host` cmdlets is actually acceptable or not.</sup>

Comment: Hi Theo! Thanks for your help. It has a lot of parsing errors. I tried using the version that i replaced every month name with numbers.
The date format now is d MM yyyy.
In the days section i've changed to this ```$days= (get-date).adddays(-$daysnumber).ToString('d MM yyyy')```
And in the Where Object I've tried ``` $data | Where-Object { ($_.$property -le $days  ) -and ($_.active -match $active) -and ($_."Jira Service Desk" -match $active)}|```
It's giving me a result, but not what I desire. It results me people that logged in recently, not  people that havent logged in the las 90 days.

Comment: @FefeGodoy Always compare dates to **dates**, not some string representation. If there are parsing errors  then the date format in the csv  is not what you described.

Comment: @FedeGodoy On closer look, your question states the headers in the CSV file as being this: `groupname,id,name,email,active,created,Last seen in software A,Last seen in software B,Last seen in software C,Software A,Software B,Software C`. However, the code you showed used very different column names.. That means there will be nothing to parse, since in the csv there are no field names like `'Last Seen in Jira Service Desk'` or `'Last Seen in Confluence'`.. Please explain what the **REAL** headers in the file are and which field maps to what.